# Map inside a Map java

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm new to java. I'm trying to pass parameters where a map is inside another map however i get an error "identifier expected"(found int, required reference).

This is the code  :

```
package learning;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 

    public interface Policy {

        public void toggleApp(Map<Map<Appliance,SimpleDateFormat>,int>toggle); *error here*

    }

     class Appliance
    {
       String appName = ""; 
       int appID; 
       double demand = 0.0;

    }
```

Comment: a map as a key to a simple type?

Comment: Try `Integer` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't provide primitive types (such as `int`) as type parameters for generic classes.

Change

```
Map<Map<Appliance,SimpleDateFormat>,int>
                                    ^^^
```

to

```
Map<Map<Appliance,SimpleDateFormat>,Integer>
                                    ^^^^^^^
```

**Also note** that the first type argument is the type of the *key* and the second type parameter is the type of the *values*. My gut feeling is that you may have swapped them in your code.

**Further reading:**

- [Lesson: Generics (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)
- [Java Generics FAQs - Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `int` as the value type of the map! `int` is a primitive and Java Generics only work for reference types.

Replace the `int` with `Integer` and it will work :-).

Since Java has [auto boxing/unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), you can use the ordinary operations and it will automatically transform `int`s to `Integer`s for you. `map.put(key, 1)` will work. It will do `Integer.intValue(1)` which is an `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parametrise a generic (like `Map<K,V>`) on a primitive type (like `int`).  Try using a wrapper class like `Integer` instead:

```
Map<Map<Appliance,SimpleDateFormat>,Integer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `int` to `Integer`.

Generics can only accept reference types as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `int` (primary type) in a `Map`, it only accepts `Objects`:

```
Map<Map<Appliance,SimpleDateFormat>, Integer > toggle;
```